# jQuery add class to middle elements in group of 3

Tags: jquery, css, fadeout, addclass

I have a set of div boxes that are dynamically created - sometimes there will be lots of boxes, sometimes there won't be many. They are laid out in rows of 3. When I click on a box it fadesOut and the box next to it fills it's space.

What I need is to give the middle boxes in each row a class "middle" - the issue I'm having is that when a box fadesOut, the middle box obviously changes.

Here is a JSfiddle demonstrating my issue. When you click on a box, if one from the middle moves, it should lose it's class and the new middle box should gain the class "middle"

http://jsfiddle.net/xmq2x/

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
$('.box:nth-child(3n+2)').addClass('middle');

$( ".box" ).click(function() {
$(this).fadeOut( "slow" );
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Filter your div's by visibility and the do some math:

```
$( ".box" ).click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut( "slow", function(){
        $( ".middle" ).removeClass("middle");
        $('.box:visible').addClass(function(i){
            if((i-1) % 3 == 0) return 'middle';
        })
    })
});
```

You can pass in `addClass` argument a function. `i` is the index of the current div.

Just make sure the function is called after the `fadeOut` occur!

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xmq2x/7/